# django split data and apply search istartswith = query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Project and when searching a query I need to split the data (not search query) in to words and apply searching.

for example:

my query is : 'bot' (typing 'bottle')

but if I use `meta_keywords__icontains = query` the filter will also return queries with 'robot'.
Here meta_keywords are keywords that can be used for searching.

I won't be able to access data if the data in meta_keywords is 'water bottle' when I use `meta_keywords__istartswith` is there any way I can use in this case.

what I just need is search in every words of data with just `istartswith`

I can simply create a model for 'meta_keywords' and use the current data to assign values by splitting and saving as different data. I know it might be the best way. I need some other ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the name field with each word that istartswith in variable query.

```
import re

instances = Model.objects.filter(Q(name__iregex=r'[[:<:]]' + re.escape(query)))
```

Eg: Hello world can be searched using the query 'hello' and 'world'. It don't check the icontains

note: It works only in Python3